# Unix regular expression

Tags: regex, unix

I need to use unix regular expression in unix find command:

> find "/home/user/somePath/" -maxdepth 1 ! -regex
>   "/home/user/somePath/someUnwantedPath" ! -regex 
>   "/home/user/somePath/someMoreUnwantedPath"

This works but I need to optimize the regex into a single one because the unwanted paths are more than just a few.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do it with alternation.

```
/home/user/somePath/(someUnwantedPath|someMoreUnwantedPath)
```

> find "/home/user/somePath/" -maxdepth 1 ! -regex "/home/user/somePath/(someUnwantedPath|someMoreUnwantedPath)"

Just add more paths at the end of the end of the parenthesized group starting with a new `|` as alternation delimiter. I.e. `|AnotherUnwantedPath`.

**Edit**

I'm a "Windows dude", so I'm not *that* familiar with Unix, but I wanted to try it out on BUW, and it appears you have to escape regex metacharacters. So I guess the correct answer should be

```
/home/user/somePath/\(someUnwantedPath\|someMoreUnwantedPath\)/.*
```

> find "/home/user/somePath/" -maxdepth 1 ! -regex "/home/user/somePath/\(someUnwantedPath\|someMoreUnwantedPath\)/.*"

Comment: and if I dont want any someUnwantedPath sub-directories not to be included as well, how can that be done?

Comment: I've updated answer to ignore all files/directories under unwanted paths - just add the `/.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -v -f` instead of regex to make it clean. The alternate (|) operator does not work in many unix systems.Your exclude files should list down all the files to be excluded(including subdirectories if any. )

```
cat excl_files.txt
/home/user/somePath/someUnwantedPath1
/home/user/somePath/someUnwantedPath2
/home/user/somePath/someUnwantedPath3
..
/home/user/somePath/someUnwantedPathn

find "/home/user/somePath/" -maxdepth 1 |  grep -v -f excl_files.txt
```